# Can’t connect iOS 17 device for live deploy with Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos, xcode14

The problem is that I can’t update for Xcode 15, that’s why I stick with Xcode 14.

Recently I updated till Xcode 14.3. Using some command from other posts on Stackoverflow, I activated CoreDevice.

Now in the list of devices I can see my phone, but it says “(CoreDevice) (Can't make device ready for development: An error occurred while communicating with a remote process.)”

I tried to reboot my Mac, then reboot my phone and reconnect it, but nothing changed.

Also, I can’t find any related questions to this problem with CoreDevice, so that’s why I need some help. How I can fix it?

[Screenshot from Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ysxel.jpg)

Comment: Please file a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com including a `devicectl diagnose`.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in your terminal

`defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode DVTEnableCoreDevice enabled`

Then restart Xcode. If this still doesn’t fix it then you will unfortunately need to update to Xcode 15